# Table datatype in a table variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to define a column datatype as table in a table variable in SQL Server?
like i tried this code

```
Declare @master table(
  idx int identity(1,1),
  ID int,
  Title nvarchar(250),
  IntegratedAccounts table(
                           AccountID int,
                           AccountTitle nvarchar(250)
                          )
)
```

I want to retrieve a result set from my table variable to populate DataTable in c# that structured as :

```
var dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("idx", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("IntegratedAccounts", typeof(DataTable));
```

Comment: There are no nested tables in SQL Server. The best alternative is usually an `xml` column (since it at least allows you to keep structure for the data)

Answer (score 2):

Answer is no you cannot in SQL. Simple as that :)

However you can relate to tables to achieve the same result with help of foreign keys

So to achieve

```
 table( (idx int identity(1,1), ID int, Title nvarchar(250), IntegratedAccounts table( AccountID int, AccountTitle nvarchar(250) ) )
```

you can make 2 tables

```
table (idx int identity(1,1), ID int, Title nvarchar(250), account_id)
```

and

```
table2(AccountID int, AccountTitle nvarchar(250) )
```

and have your `table.account_id references to table2.AccountID`

That may help you achieve what you want to..